# Get date of next years first week strtotime

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, strtotime, time-format

I'm trying to get the date of the first week in 2015 and its really frustrating.

This works:

```
strtotime("2014W17-1")
```

it returns `2014-04-27`

But when I call:

```
strtotime("2015W1-1")
```

it returns `1970-01-01`

Hmm. Whats wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been stupid!

Easy fix:

```
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime("2015W01"));
```

Or if looking at your code, just add a `0`.

```
echo date("d/my/Y", strtotime("2015W01-1"));
```

Comment: I know... But What IF i want The date of second week in 2015.

Comment: Oh. Ok sorry Kind of misunderstood, hold on I'll look into it.

Comment: And the first week in 2015 starts in 2014

Comment: @ThomasBolander I've been really stupid and just had a sudden realization! I've fixed it for you, simple and same style as your code.